# Offsets In Azure Event Hubs

Tags: azure

I have a small client application sending data to an Azure event hub, and another application reading from it.

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn789972.aspx, you can include an offset in the event hub receiver. I'm looking to include an offset in the form of the timestamp as mentioned on MSDN. Does anyone know how to do this? I can easily include the numerical string format for the offest (e.g string myOffset = "12345", but I can't seem to get the timestamp format.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "can't seem to get the timestamp format", but when you create your receiver, you pass a DateTime data type to the CreateReceiver method.

```
public EventHubReceiver CreateReceiver(
    string partitionId,
    DateTime startingDateTimeUtc,
    long epoch
)
```

See MSDN on CreateReceiver:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn790504.aspx

If you have the timestamp as a string, you might try the DateTime.Parse (or TryParse) method to get the DateTime value.

```
    string MyString = "Aug 25, 2015";
    DateTime MyDateTime = DateTime.Parse(MyString);
```

See more on MSDN for Parsing Time:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57(v=vs.110).aspx